# Attempt to parallelize not fast enough

Tags: go, concurrency

I read about Go's concurrency model and also saw about the difference between concurrency and parallelism. In order to test parallel execution, I wrote the following program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const count = 1e8

var buffer [count]int

func main() {
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS: ", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))

    // Initialise with dummy value
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        buffer[i] = 3
    }

    // Sequential operation
    now := time.Now()
    worker(0, count-1)
    fmt.Println("sequential operation: ", time.Since(now))

    // Attempt to parallelize
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    now = time.Now()
    go func() {
        worker(0, (count/2)-1)
        ch <- 1
    }()
    worker(count/2, count-1)
    <-ch
    fmt.Println("parallel operation: ", time.Since(now))
}

func worker(start int, end int) {
    for i := start; i <= end; i++ {
        task(i)
    }
}

func task(index int) {
    buffer[index] = 2 * buffer[index]
}
```

But the problem is: the results are not very pleasing.

```
GOMAXPROCS:  8
sequential operation:  206.85ms
parallel operation:  169.028ms
```

Using a goroutine does speed things up but not enough. I expected it to be closer to being twice as fast. What is wrong with my code and/or understanding? And how can I get closer to being twice as fast?

Comment: You're parallelizing an extremely trivial operation. I'm surprised it sped up at all, given the overhead of concurrency is more than the time it takes to do a single integer multiply.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for pointing that out. Is it probable that using a more complex operation would give a better distinction in compute time? And have I parallelized the operation correctly?

Comment: Yes, if you parallelize work that takes time, and there are cores to spread it across, then you should generally see performance improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallelization is powerful, but it's hard to see with such a small computational load. Here is some sample code with a larger difference in the result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func calctest(nCPU int) {
    fmt.Println("Routines:", nCPU)
    ch := make(chan float64, nCPU)
    startTime := time.Now()
    a := 0.0
    b := 1.0
    n := 100000.0
    deltax := (b - a) / n

    stepPerCPU := n / float64(nCPU)
    for start := 0.0; start < n; {
        stop := start + stepPerCPU
        go f(start, stop, a, deltax, ch)
        start = stop
    }

    integral := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < nCPU; i++ {
        integral += <-ch
    }

    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(startTime))
    fmt.Println(deltax * integral)
}

func f(start, stop, a, deltax float64, ch chan float64) {
    result := 0.0
    for i := start; i < stop; i++ {
        result += math.Sqrt(a + deltax*(i+0.5))
    }
    ch <- result
}

func main() {
    nCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    calctest(nCPU)
    fmt.Println("")
    calctest(1)
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
Routines: 8
853.181µs

Routines: 1
2.031358ms
```